# help with PHP session_destroy();

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have several forms brought in via jQuery .ajax funciton. In the parent page I start a session like this

```
<php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 'yes';
?>
```

then in the form that is loaded have a check like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != 'yes') {
  header("Location: http://www.google.com");
 }
?>
```

I know its not the best, but it's an attempt to stop people form accessing the forms directly. The problem is that if you go to the parent page, then you can enter the form URL and get there because the session was started when you hit the parent page. How can I destroy the session or remedy this issue?

Comment: Please try to explain why you want to have this check? Which forms are people not allowed to access directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your form .php code to see where the request is coming from. An AJAX call will set the HTTP_REFERER to the page it is called from.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) === false) {
   die();
}
```

It's not a bulletproof solution. Any page that is publicly accessible can be retrieved by an automated script.

Comment: @Dimitry - what is the standard solution for something like this?

Comment: I've wrestled with the idea of public forms not being spammed by automated bots. The solution is to introduce an action that only a human can solve. Unfortunately, that means CAPTCHAs or authentication. You can also use facebook/google/linkedin login as a means to ensure your user is not a bot.

Comment: Also check `$_SERVER['X_REQUESTED_WITH']`.

Comment: @sexyprout - so it will make sure it is an xmlhttp request correct?

Comment: Yes. jQuery always sends this header on XHR requests.

Comment: @sexyprout - so how would I code that up? I would like to do something like this: if (xmlhttprequest is false){ header("Locaiton:someotherpage.com");} i know its wrong

Comment: if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] !== 'XMLHttpRequest')
{
  header("Location: http://www.somedomain.com/page.php");
}

Comment: Just add what Dirty Bird Design said in your echo statement, it's a second check.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, you can't.

To make it more complicated, don't request the form URLs directly. Try to request **authorize tokens per request** of the main page:

- If you generate the main page and you know the form to be requested beforehand, then generate tokens e.g. using md5(time().rnd()), associate each with one you your forms and save the association in your session
- Then, your JS code won't request the form URLs, but a factory script using a token injected into the JS code
- If you find the token in your saved association in your session, emit the form and **delete the token** in your session.

This way, each form can only be requested once by one preceding call of the main page.

Note, that this isn't fully safe too: If a user requests the URL of the main page using *wget*, he can request each form once.

Comment: Pantke - at the time being, that is beyond my understanding. Hopefully in the future I will be able to accomplish something like that.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - In case you are going to give it a try and need further assistance, just continue here.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. My parent page loads the form via click function with .load from a js file, which also includes all the validation.